# Transition in element from right

Tags: css

I have the following element that is transitioning from left to right, how do I get it to transition from right to left without any gaps between the element and the right of the page.

```css
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

header {
  /* This section calls the slideInFromLeft animation we defined above */
  animation: 5s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #333;
  padding: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Test
</header>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yy3qtbef/1/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the undesired gap, you need to get rid of the *default margin* with the `margin: 0` (or you can give it to the *body element*), to slide it from the *right*, position it there with the `right: 0`, and change the value of the `transform` property to `translateX(100%)`, which will make sure that the element is off the screen before it slides to the left:

```css
header {
  animation: 5s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #333;
  margin: 0; /* added */
  padding: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  right: 0; /* added */
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes slideInFromRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%); /* modified */
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>Test</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand your question, Add

```
right: 20px
```

to the .header class and change -

```
translateX(-100%)
```

to

```
translateX(100%)
```

Here is the demo - https://jsfiddle.net/r0jf2a1y/

Comment: Since the OP asks about "no gaps", may be the idea would be right: 0px;

Comment: Left to right transition was having some space on the left so that's why I added a little space to right too.